# publish a facebook app

Tags: facebook

I have a web site "www.chatmic.com", and I joined Developer app in facebook and went throw the "set up a new application" wizard. my Application is Iframe of my site www.chatmic.com

when I want to publish it I get the message "to publish you need at list 3 users...." 
how can I get users ?
I can only get fans 
when I send the link to my application http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=177721458320 to my friends ... they see only "become a fun" button

10X

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application doesn't request authorization from users.  It's just an IFRAME of your site that happens to be shown within Facebook.  As such, it isn't really a Facebook app.  You can implement [Facebook Connect](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect) and/or the [Javascript Client Library](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JavaScript_Client_Library) on your site and this will allow you to prompt users to add the app and use other Facebook features.

(**Edit adding further info:**) To really provide value to your users you will want to integrate Facebook a little deeper (there's no point really having them access it via Facebook unless they can use their Facebook profile info there), in which case you may want to [integrate Facebook into your server-side user session management](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Using_Facebook_Connect_with_Server-Side_Libraries), or at very least add some widgets using [XFBML](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/XFBML).  But if all you want is users to the app, at a minimum you just need to implement the JS API's requireLogin() or Facebook Connect's requireSession().

Comment: >> But if all you want is users to the app, at a minimum you just need to implement the JS API's requireLogin() or Facebook Connect's requireSession().
BTW, I would guess this is probably frowned upon at least a little by Facebook, and they might choose not to list you in the directory.  If you're going to make an app it should actually tie in Facebook features to some level, rather than just using Facebook as another directory to submit your site to.

Comment: 10X a lot man, you really helped me understand 
and think again on how I should build a facebook app.
10X again great answer !!